# How to make a <select> that will select the file that will be used to draw the chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have a graph that is drawn with data from an external file. Now I would like to have a select in which the user can select the file to be read. That way the graph would change dynamically. How can I do this using vue and chartjs?

Currently I import the data in Home like this

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Graph :vul_data="data"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Graph from '@/components/Graph.vue';
import {data} from '@/data/dataFile.js'

@Component({
  components: {
    Graph,
  },
})
export default class HomeView extends Vue {
  data() {
    return {
      data: data,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Each files has the data like this:

```
export const data = {
    "points": {
      "line1": {
        "x": [
          -11,
          -11,
        ],
        "y": [
          7,
          8,
        ]
      },
    },
}
```

The component is like that:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

export default{
  name: "Graph",
  props: ["vul_data"],

  mounted(){
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Line 1',            
            data:[
              {x: this.vul_data.points.line1.x[0], y: this.vul_data.points.line1.y[0]},
              {x: this.vul_data.points.line1.x[1], y: this.vul_data.points.line1.y[1]},
            ],
          }, 
          ] 
        },
    });
  }
}
</script>
<style>
  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `<select>` with options containing values equal to your .js filenames.  When the selection is changed, run a method that dynamically imports that file and assigns the imported data to the variable you pass down as a prop to your Graph component.  Simple example code:

```html
<select @change="selectFile">
  <option value="dataFile1">file one</option>
  <option value="dataFile2">file two</option>
</select>
<Graph :vul_data="data" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    data: null,
  };
},
methods: {
  selectFile(e) {
    import(`@/data/${e.target.value}.js`).then((res) => {
      this.data = res.data;
    });
  },
},
```

Comment: Good idea, but there is a problem with the Vue method this way. "Property 'methods' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor". Do you know why?

Comment: my code is in standard Vue SFC syntax.  you're using class component syntax which I'm admittedly not familiar with.  looks like you don't need to define a [methods property](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#methods), just place `selectFile` directly inside your component class

Comment: I tried just place SelectFile directly inside my component class, but it looks like the event listener is not being recognized. "Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: that sounds like a typescript warning to me.  shouldn't prevent the method from working, but to resolve you can change `selectFile(e)` to `selectFile(e: Event)` to declare `e` as having an `Event` type which should make typescript happy

Comment: It doesn't work :/